# Why does `tmpfs` reads/writes to disk on file creation/deletion?

Tags: ubuntu, files, filesystems, mount, tmpfs

Question: why are there both disk reads and writes when I create or delete files on a `tmpfs`?

The `tmpfs` is mounted with `mount -t tmpfs -o size=1G tmpfs "/SCRATCHSPACE"` in `/etc/rc.local` (add to `/etc/rc.local`, run `mkdir /SCRATCHSPACE`, and then reboot computer to mount the `tmpfs`). As far as I know, the file contents are stored in RAM and file inode/metadata are also stored in RAM

Bash script for file creation, writing, and deletion:

```
cd /SCRATCHSPACE
for i in {0..10000}; do echo foobar > $i; rm $i; done
```

or

```
cd /SCRATCHSPACE
touch {0..10000} && rm {0..10000}
```

The hard drive usage indicator starts up right after running the above code. To make sure I wasn't just imagining it, I also use:

```
grep -e Dirty: -e Writeback: /proc/meminfo
```

which correlates with the file creation/deletion. The dirty and writeback jumps up from `0 KB` to `500 KB` consistently. If I increase the number of files created in Bash script, the `Dirty` scales up linearly. To flush the write (not necessary), run `sync`. I can hear the hard drive move when I wait after running the Bash scripts (even without `sync`)

This is reproducible on both Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 20.04 where swap is turned off

Additional information:

```bsh
$ df -h /SCRATCHSPACE
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.0G  10M  1.0G  0% /SCRATCHSPACE

$ cat /proc/swaps
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority

$ cat /etc/fstab
UUID=<36 characters for UUID> /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=<10 characters for UUID>  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
```

No antivirus, loggers, or anything of that sort has been installed (only whatever shipped with Ubuntu)

The OS (both 16.04 and 20.04) were installed by live USB (clean install). It was not upgraded from one version to the other

Comment: Are you sure your `tmpfs` is actually mounted?

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes, with `df -h /SCRATCHSPACE` shows `Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on\ntmpfs           1.0G  10M  1.0G  0% /SCRATCHSPACE` (more readable: Filesystem: `tmpfs`, Size: `1.0G`, Used: `10M`, Avail: `1.0G`, Use%: `0%`, Mounted on: `/SCRATCHSPACE`)

Comment: swap? `cat /proc/swaps`?

Comment: @UncleBilly No swap. Output of `cat /proc/swaps`: `Filename    Type  Size Used Priority`

Comment: Has auditing been enabled/configured? It might be producing audit log entries to `/var/log/audit/` or to a custom location.

Comment: @telcoM No. It is a personal computer and I have not enabled auditing (I don't think Ubuntu has auditing on by default). I've checked `/var/log` and none were updated recently (except `syslog`, but the contents are reasonable)